# How can I calculate the average of the sum of 2 columns in ORACLE?

Tags: oracle

I have the table `EMPLOYEES` with columns `EMPLOYEE_ID`, `NAME`, `SALARY`, `COMMISSION_PCT`.

I have to calculate the average salary of employees taking into account commissions.

How can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you said:

```
select avg(sal + nvl(comm, 0)) avg_sal_comm
from emp
```

If commission part is expressed as *percentage*, then

```
select avg(sal + sal * nvl(comm, 0) / 100) avg_sal_comm
from emp;
```

`NVL` is here because not all employees have `comm` column value.